# How to send base64 authorization in Python

Tags: python, cookies, base64, python-requests, urllib2

I need to send my user id and password in `base64` format to an API URL and the output of the API URl are a set of cookies which I need to pass to the subsequent API URLS. How can i do this?

I'm using the below code, but i get HTTP 403 as response.

```
import requests, base64
usrPass = "dev:password1"
b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass)
r=requests.post('http://127.0.0.0/example/rest/authenticate', 
                headers={"Authorization": "Basic %s" % b64Val},
                data=None)
```

Authorization Format: "Authorization: Basic sdkjASDLFHsdlfk13AA="

Am i doing it the right way with the above code?

Secondly, Post authentication, it returns a set of cookies. How do i save those cookies and pass it to the next API URL?

Comment: 403 is forbidden which is related to permissions, 401 is the code for authorization failure. your auth seems to be working fine. also a small thought if you are using `"dev:password1"` where `dev` is your username and `password1` is your password, you are using `:` as a separator, you should make sure that none of the username or password should have the `:` otherwise while decoding if you need to check the validity of your token, you might face problems.

Comment: thanks, I also tried using different variables for user id and password and still encounter the same issue.

Comment: you might need to share some more details of your API, how in fact, does the API expect the base64 encoded parameters, other parameters/headers which it might be expecting.

Comment: this is the format the api needs authorization - `Authorization: Basic sdkjASDLFHsdlfk13AA=` and nothing else apart from the authorization. this works perfectly fine with curl command but when i am trying it using python, i face the issue.